# Scala : append Array to List

Tags: arrays, scala, list

I'm trying to append Array to List When writing data into a csv file as follows.

But, each Array was not appended to the List.
How can I append each Array to a List.

Please help me with this.

```
import java.io.StringWriter
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.io.BufferedWriter

var out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/Users/TestCom/Desktop/test_4.csv"));
var writer = new CSVWriter(out);
var outputSchema = Array("name","0h","20h")
var listOfRecords = List(outputSchema)

var numIters = 0
for(numIters <- 0 to 1){

    var testVal1 = numIters + 1
    var testVal2 = numIters + 2

    var eachArr = Array(testVal1, testVal2)
    listOfRecords ++ eachArr
}

writer.writeAll(listOfRecords)
out.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your line that does `listOfRecords ++ eachArr` to be `listOfRecords = listOfRecords ++ eachArr`.

The list is immutable so you must reassign after appending.

Comment: Thank you so much. Additionally, "listOfRecords = listOfRecords ++ eachArr" made a mismatch error. So, I changed the code to "listOfRecords = listOfRecords ++ List(eachArr)"

Comment: Glad to help. Happy coding!